# Error Code: 1239. Incorrect foreign key definition for 'foreign key without name': reference and table don't match

Tags: mysql, dbms

I'm making a new database in MySQL in which after making the Department table I receive an error when adding other tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Department (dept_name varchar(20), building varchar(15), budget numeric(12,2), primary key(dept_name));

CREATE TABLE Course (course_id varchar(7), title varchar(50), dept_name varchar(20),credits numeric(2,0), primary key(course_id),
 foreign key(dept_name) references Department);

CREATE TABLE Instructor (ID varchar (5),name varchar (20) not null,dept_name varchar (20),salary numeric (8,2),primary key (ID),
foreign key (dept_name) references Department);
```

I had a look at [Error 1239: Incorrect foreign key definition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/212787/error-1239-incorrect-foreign-key-definition)   but it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add column name along with table name.

```
  CREATE TABLE Department (dept_name varchar(20), building varchar(15), budget numeric(12,2), primary key(dept_name));

        CREATE TABLE Course (course_id varchar(7), title varchar(50), dept_name varchar(20),credits numeric(2,0), primary key(course_id),
         foreign key(dept_name) references Department(dept_name));

        CREATE TABLE Instructor (ID varchar (5),name varchar (20) not null,dept_name varchar (20),salary numeric (8,2),primary key (ID),
        foreign key (dept_name) references Department(dept_name));
```

Comment: odd my 6th edtion book  database concepts  didn't type it that way. i put it in line per line ....ughh. anyhow it worked Thanks.

Comment: Yes, referencing only the table is valid SQL syntax (when you want to reference the PK) but MYSQL hasn't implemented it yet.